# Showing that $\int (\partial_i f) h^j g^{ij} dV = 0$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $h$ a vector field on $M$ that vanishes on the boundary and which is divergence free. I would like to show that, using coordinates,
$$\int (\partial_i f) h^j g^{ij} dV = 0$$
where $dV = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$ is the Riemannian volume form. Thus the integral becomes
$$\int (\partial_i f) h^j g^{ij} \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} dx = 0 \tag{1}$$
where I have written $dx = dx^1\cdots dx^n$ for convenience.

In local coordinates the divergence takes the form
$$Div(h) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}}\partial_i\Big(h^i\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}\Big).$$

My first approach was to integrate (1) by parts to get
$$\int (\partial_i f) h^j g^{ij} \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} dx = -\int f(\partial_ih^j)g^{ij}\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} dx -\int fh^j\partial_i(g^{ij})\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} dx -\int fh^jg^{ij}\partial_i\big(\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}\big) dx \\
= -\int fh^j\partial_i(g^{ij})\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} dx - \int fg^{ij}\partial_i\Big(h^j\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}\Big) dx $$
The last term looks a lot like the definition of the divergence other than the factor of the square root but the index on the partial derivative does not match the index of $h$. I also do not see how the first term after the last inequality can be made to vanish without anymore information.

Does anyone know how I can proceed?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150032/discussion-on-question-by-cbbam-showing-that-int-partial-i-f-hj-gij-dv); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.